# Java List is not populating

Tags: java, arraylist, android-recyclerview

```
   public void initValue(){
 LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); rvLIsta.setLayoutManager(manager); elements = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=1; i>= 5;i++ ){            
        elements.add( new Data("House Name","texas","@+id/home" ));
    }
  

    listAdapter = new Adapter(elements, this);
    rvLIsta.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvLIsta.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rvLIsta.setAdapter( listAdapter);

}
```

Im trying to populate a RecyclerView with this For Loop but is not adding the data to the element's list.

Comment: Where is `elements` variable **defined**?

Comment: I just figured out my for loop was incorrect It was i < 5